# getElementById and null - why?

Tags: javascript, html, null, onclick

Why doesn't this code work? I'am using FF.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("someID").onclick = function(){
    alert("Yahooo");
}
</script> 
</head>

<body> 
<a href="#" id="someID">someID</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm getting javascript error getElementById equals to null.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The needed DOM is not loaded when the script is executed. Either move it down (below the href) or define it like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("someID").onclick = function(){
        alert("Yahooo");
    }
}
```

window.onload will be called when the page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Because the element doesn't yet exist when the script runs - the document hasn't been rendered yet.  Either run the script in a script block after the related HTML, or use a "document on ready" event handler - preferably from something like jQuery's [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, or the native `window.onload`.