# Change Text using JS

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the text of textbox/input by JavaScript, when its clicked

```
var txtSearch = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
        txtSearch.onmousedown= txtClear;

        function txtClear() {
            txtSearch.value = "";
        }
```

Comment: `onclick`, instead of _onmouseover_

Comment: @c69 thanks, but still not working

Comment: can you add a jsFiddle example of your code, which is not working ?

Comment: So what's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/w7uhg/

Comment: The code you've provided in the question does not give enough information for people to reproduce the problem. You need to provide a more complete test case before anyone can actually solve the problem.

Comment: @ nkmol now saying this is totally out of sense that for some unknown reason its not working from Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a browser. Test code in browsers.

Comment: @Quentin Obviously I tested in a Browser

Comment: Where does the above Javascript appear in the HTML file? If it's before the HTML that creates the `txtSearch` element, then `document.getElementById()` will return `null`.

Comment: @Barmar yah its before

Comment: That's your problem. Either put it after, or put the code in the `window.onload` handler.

Comment: @Barmar Great Response dude.. That Was the actual problem, but can you little more illustrate what window.onload is.

Comment: @Faizan Did you see my answer below?

Comment: Hmm. If that was the actual issue, why did my response get downvoted? It's almost looking like someone was just trying to maliciously lower scores for answers to this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the handler after the DOM is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var txtSearch = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
    txtSearch.onmousedown= txtClear;
};
```

Otherwise, it can't find the `txtSearch` element if your Javascript appears before the body of the HTML.

Comment: What if my script is on different page?

Comment: Different pages can't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, so if I'm correct...this is actually a common early mistake. I'm assuming this is your whole Javascript? It's not wrapped in any function? If that's the case, this question also should help with the answer:

[getElementById and null - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864776/getelementbyid-and-null-why)

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) on your object and use the `focus` event like so (assuming the element in question here is an input):

```
document.getElementById("txtSearch").addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
    event.target.value = txtClear();
});
```

Note that you don't have to use a `function` to set the value (and if you do, you'll need it to `return` the value you want, or pass it the `event` as a parameter and modify that object); you could just as easily use an empty string (`event.target.value = ''`).

Comment: Using `addEventListener` is generally preferred to setting `onXXX` directly (despite having weaker browser support), but that's a code style issue, not a fix. The code in the question is calling a function that sets the value to an empty string, it isn't setting the value to the return value of that function call.

Comment: Sure, and it would be up to the OP to have his function actually return something useful (ie : return ''), or to update the code in question to pass the event as a parameter to the `txtClear` function and use that locally. I make a note of that immediately below the example.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with just one line and still working:

```
document.getElementById("txtSearch").onmousedown = function() { this.value = "" }
```

Comment: ?? why the flag, thumbs down, it is working in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dpamio/gU5wL/1/

Answer (score -3):

What you are doing is writing code that alters an internal variable.  You did nothing to write that information to the page or "screen", if you will.  The variable foo.value is more for the use of capturing text or a value, rather than writing it out.

Use document.write(xxxx); as a method to write something to a page or alter the existing HTML.

Comment: I'd really recommend against the use of document.write unless someone is just writing a 3-minute test page...The more straightforward way of thinking is just "`value` is the wrong property" EDIT: (which, in this case, I don't think is even true)

Comment: `document.write` will blow away the entire page since it is being called after the page has finished rendering.

Comment: In this case, it was an example of the proper way to write information as opposed to getting information, not a solution per se.

Comment: If you want to inform someone of "the proper way" to do something, it's generally more suited to a comment than an answer. What's more, 'document.write' has never been "the proper way" in my experience. Both innerHTML and `createElement`/`appendChild` are preferable.

Comment: As you yourself stated, document.write can be used in very small pages.  If you would have looked at the code the person provided, it is a total of maybe 8 lines of code and involves a massive use of a single text box.  Why would anyone go about altering that by creating elements and using child elements?

Comment: He's not writing something to the page or altering the existing HTML. He's trying to change the content of an `<input>` field, which is done by assigning to the `value` property.

Comment: The size of a page has little to do with the applicability of document.write anyway. What matters is *when* it runs (before or after domready).

Comment: It can be done that way, but look at the entire page.  It is literally a one liner.  There are countless ways to do it and as I see it there is no reason to do things the way he is trying to do it unless there is a lot more to handle than that single piece of HTML.